# How schedule a job for a query which references multiple databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, scheduler, multiple-databases

I have a query that I need to schedule to run on the first of every month. The query pulls data from two databases that have identical schema/structure but different data, and it unions them together.

My problem is that the SSMS scheduler requires that I designate a database, which seems to indicate that I can only query against one db at a time.

Querying against multiple databases is a fairly common task so I would think there has to be a way to automate this but I have not been able to find anything thus far.

Is there a way to do this? Do I have to use SSIS?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can include three- and four- part naming in your queries, so your queries can access any database.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that is what I am doing in my query to reference the multiple databases. The problem is that the scheduler also requires you to select a single database to run the query against. Are the naming conventions in the query supposed to override the database selection in the scheduler? I can try again but that wasn't working in my tests.

Comment: The current database is used only as the default database when more specific information is not provided.  Of course, the SQL Server Agent needs to have access to the other databases in order for the job to be able to access the data.

Answer (score 2):

Use three part name.

```
use tempdb
go

select 'master', count(*) as 'total' from [master].sys.objects
union
select 'msdb', count(*) as 'total' from msdb.sys.objects
union
select 'tempdb', count(*) as 'total' from tempdb.sys.objects
go
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, similar to my comment above... I am including three part naming in my query to reference the multiple databases, the query works when I run it manually but not when I schedule it. The problem is that the scheduler requires you to select a single database to run the query against. Are the naming conventions in the query supposed to override the database selection in the scheduler? I can try again but that wasn't working in my tests

Comment: It doesn't matter what database you set, as long as you reference your db in three part name.  You can set it to master and it should still work.  Post an error if that is what you are getting.